# readlines() not reading from file

Tags: python, io

I am new to python and I have just been messing around with I/O and after using readlines() my code says that the file is blank, it ran once properly while I was testing and messing around with my for loop. I have been reading about this issue and found out that I am at the end of file. I have tried using seek(0) but it does not appear to be working as my code still is outputting a `<BLANKLINE>`. I haven't found any solutions to this but I would appreciate if somebody could help me figure it out. I have checked test.txt to make sure that there is still something in there and there is.

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
file.seek(0) #I added this after my issue started
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(lines)
file.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like your file is empty. Maybe the file you are checking is not the file it is reading.

Comment: I don't believe this is the problem as I have checked the filepath and the files within